# loop doesn't break and invalid input always shown

Tags: java, loops, input

part of my code where you can play a puzzle with the idea of retuning a shuffled 4x4 number array back to its original state. the user enters certain command e.g. row 0 row 1, and a loop does the command, prints the latest puzzle then asks for the command and should end when the puzzle matches the original state of the puzzle. my loop never breaks when back to the original puzzle and constantly prints invalid input even when correct input has been entered. how can i fix these problems? *this is just the play method part of the code*

```
static void play(int[][] puzzle) {
        reset(puzzle);
        int[][] z = new int[N][N];
        reset(z);
        print(puzzle);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           randomRotation(puzzle);

        }

        print(puzzle);


        while (puzzle!=z) {
            System.out.println("enter row x or col x: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String x = input.nextLine();
            if (!x.equals("row 0") || !x.equals("row 1") ||!x.equals( "row 2") ||!x.equals( "row 3") ||!x.equals( "col 0") ||!x.equals( "col 1") ||!x.equals( "col 2") ||!x.equals("col3")) {
                System.out.println("invalid input");
            }



            if (x.equals("row 0")) {
                rotateRow(puzzle, 0);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("row 1")) {
                rotateRow(puzzle, 1);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("row 2")) {
                rotateRow(puzzle, 2);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("row 3")) {
                rotateRow(puzzle, 3);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("col 0")) {
                rotateColumn(puzzle, 0);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("col 1")) {
                rotateColumn(puzzle, 1);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("col 2")) {
                rotateColumn(puzzle, 2);
                print(puzzle);

            }
            if (x.equals("col 3")) {
                rotateColumn(puzzle, 3);
                print(puzzle);
            }


        }
```

}

Comment: "row 0" is not "row 1" and "row 1" is not "row 0"  I suggest you use a switch statement to combine all these checks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `continue` after `System.out.println("invalid input");`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Boolean is backwards.  Saying "is not ... or is not ... or is not ..." So unless it's Schroedinger's cat and is all those values at the same time, the test will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues and inefficiencies in your code, but this is the problem you're asking about: Your while should be `!puzzle.equals(z)` instead of `puzzle!=z`. Arrays are not primitives and as such two different declarations of arrays, even if their contents are the same, will never be equal by memory (`==`).

Also, you should make all of your `if`s into `else if`s and move the invalid input to the bottom as an `else`. The `else` will then correct your problem of using ors instead of ands.

Comment: the invalid input part worked! however the loop still doesn't break! any other ideas? cheers though! :) @Zircon